# How to set edittext editable dynamically by click an imagebutton?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

I list dynamically string values from an ArrayList into EditTexts with a for loop, and ImageButtons are next to every EditText. I want this: when I click an ImageButton, the corresponsive EditText be editable.
Here is my code from the activity:

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View showProduct = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_show_product, null);

for (int i = 0; i < product.size(); ++i) {
    final EditText edt_row_show_product = (EditText) showProduct.findViewById(R.id.edt_row_show_product);
    edt_row_show_product.setText(product.get(i));
    ImageButton ib_row_show_product_edit_icon = (ImageButton)showProduct.findViewById(R.id.ib_row_show_product_edit_icon);

    ib_row_show_product_edit_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //container.getParent()...;
        }
    });

    container.addView(showProduct);
}
```

Comment: Make array of ids of ImageButtons and EditTexts. Then do same thing what u have done.

Answer (score 2):

I made a quick app to make your requirement work. Please take a look.

I had the code working in a Fragment so if you are working in an Activity please make the required changes.

Fragment Code:

```
package viewtest.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public FragVisibilityInterface mInterface = null;

    private LinearLayout showProduct, editTextsLL;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mInterface = new FragVisibilityInterface() {
            @Override
            public void toggleFragVisibility() {

            }
        };
    }

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        //Button testBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.testbutton);

        /*testBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hideFrag();
            }
        }); */
        String [] myArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.populate_array);
        ArrayList<String> product = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(myArray));





        for (int i = 0; i < product.size(); ++i){
            View showProd = createNewTextView(product.get(i));
            LinearLayout editTextLL = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextsLL);
            editTextLL.addView(showProd);
            showProd = null;
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    /*private void hideFrag() {
        SecondActivityFragment secFrag = new SecondActivityFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, secFrag, "SecFrag").commit();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(this).commit();
    }*/

    private View createNewTextView(String text) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View showProduct = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_text_layout, null);
        final EditText edt_row_show_product = (EditText) showProduct.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        edt_row_show_product.setText(text);
        Button ib_row_show_product_edit_icon =(Button) showProduct.findViewById(R.id.button);

        ib_row_show_product_edit_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                edt_row_show_product.requestFocusFromTouch();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(edt_row_show_product, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

            }
        });
        return showProduct;
    }

    public interface FragVisibilityInterface{
        public void toggleFragVisibility();
    }
}
```

EditText and Button Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Edit"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main Fragment Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
        android:text="Button"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/editTextsLL"
        android:layout_below="@id/testbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The code may be a little rough around the edges as it was made real quick. Please make relevant changes. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set set the tag of the imageview with the corresponding EditText and get the tag in the `onClick`

```
final EditText edt_row_show_product = (EditText) showProduct.findViewById(R.id.edt_row_show_product);

edt_row_show_product.setText(product.get(i));           

ImageButton ib_row_show_product_edit_icon =(ImageButton)showProduct.findViewById(R.id.ib_row_show_product_edit_icon);

ib_row_show_product_edit_icon.setTag(edt_row_show_product); //set the Edittext object here above

ib_row_show_product_edit_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    EditText et = (EditText)v.getTag()
                    //do what ever you want with the EditText
                }
            });
```

Comment: @andris11m one more way is to create and arraylist and add edittext while you set the index of the edittext to the tag of imageview just like above.